# cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

It's very strange error to my mind

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'head': [1, 1,2,2,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,2, 3,3], 
                  'appraisal': [1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,1,2,3,4,5]})
```

then

```
df.loc[df.head, 'appraisal'].mean()
```

and

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers
```

But if i change 'head' to for ample 'head_id' it works correct

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'head_id': [1, 1,2,2,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,2, 3,3], 
                  'appraisal': [1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,1,2,3,4,5]})
df.loc[df.head_id, 'appraisal'].mean()
2.0
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) is function of pandas, so need `[]`, same is impossible use `df.sum`, `df.min` - but works `df['sum']`, `df['mean']`:

```
df.loc[df['head'], 'appraisal'].mean()

#if change 'head' to 'head1' it works
df.loc[df.head1, 'appraisal'].mean()
```

[**Attribute Access** in docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access):

> You can use this access only if the index element is a valid python identifier, e.g. s.1 is not allowed. See here for an explanation of valid identifiers.
>
> The attribute will not be available if it conflicts with an existing method name, e.g. **s.min** is not allowed.
>
> Similarly, the attribute will not be available if it conflicts with any of the following list: index, major_axis, minor_axis, items, labels.
>
> In any of these cases, standard indexing will still work, e.g. s['1'], s['min'], and s['index'] will access the corresponding element or column.
>
> The Series/Panel accesses are available starting in 0.13.0.

Comment: yes, but what's wrong witn 'head' and correct with 'head_id'?

Comment: because `head_id` is not pandas function, so it works perfectly.